# Is there a single word for 'beyond the hype'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to phrase "beyond the hype Cloud computing" tersely. I've been racking my brains for a single word, trying to get it into the form:

> [word] Cloud Computing

I thought of:

> Real Cloud Computing

But I want a word that hints at the fact `Cloud` is a buzzword and inverts it. Intuitively I feel the word is out there somewhere!

Btw, this is for a writeup/report, not for advertising. The full context might be a statement to the effect that ***such and such carry out*** [*word*] ***Cloud Computing***.

Comment: Please provide the entire sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about **hype-free** Cloud Computing?

Or a bit oxymoronic, **down-to-Earth** Cloud Computing?

Comment: I like the oxymoron! Hits the irreverent tone I wanted (but did not mention in the question) :D

Answer (score 3):

Similar in feel to bib’s answer (which may be preferable): *Cloud Computing, Cloud Nine*.

Or *Unfogging Cloud Computing*.

Answer (score 2):

- Practical Cloud Computing
- Cloud Computing in Practice
- Pragmatic Cloud Computing

Answer (score 1):

I would simply say, “distributed computing” (or “networked.., shared.., or scaled.. – etc.) if you’re trying to speak to the actual system architecture, or trying to highlight a unique attribute of the architecture.

If you’re grinding an axe against buzzwords (in my opinion a wholly satisfying and worthwhile undertaking) then I would make a joke of it and say something like the “..Cloudy Interweb Computing”, or integrate something half funny - depending on the audience and intent.